# using rsync between 2 ubuntu servers having a folder with SPACE in the name, how to make it work?

Tags: rsync, migration, syntax

I used rsync alot, but never found out how to copy a folder which had a space in the name.

like this :

```
sudo rsync -rv myuseraccount@192.168.xxx.xx:/data/svn/my folder /data/svn/
```

i tried already various versions like :

```
sudo rsync -rv myuseraccount@192.168.xxx.xx:"/data/svn/my folder" /data/svn/
```

or

```
sudo rsync -rv myuseraccount@192.168.xxx.xx:"/data/svn/my folder/" /data/svn/
```

whats the correct syntax to copy a folder which has a space in his name ?

OKAY GOT IT :

using a ' to escape my shell 
and backslash for the remote shell

```
sudo rsync -rv 'myuseraccount@192.168.xxx.xx:/data/svn/my\ folder/' /data/svn/
```

Comment: replace the space with \ and recheck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A space in a name is no problem, as long as you put the directory step between "". for example `/home/james/"some folder"`

It is not rsync that cannot handle the space, but the shell that assumes the command ends at the space.

Comment: yes i just found out. i need a single quote to escape my shell and backslash for remote shell

Comment: @Private ah, in my reflex, missed the remote element. both " and ' works by the way.